# Histogram in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

[image]When I tried to do an Histogram, the Rectangles shown are separated, how to make them related the one next to other (remove spaces)

This is a part of my code:

```
public DrawRectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = 100 - height - 1;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;

    box = new Rectangle();

    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width + 1, 100));
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    boite.setLocation(x, y);
    boite.setSize(width, height);
    g2.draw(box);
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please take a screen shot of your GUI and tell us what you want to change in the GUI.

Comment: I posted a picture. I want to remove the spaces between Rectangles

Comment: It looks to me like you need to make changes to code not shown. Good luck.

Comment: @Khan - what hovercraft means is please post the entire code for running the histogram. People will be able to help you then. I don't know if many people have the time to imagine the missing pieces of your code and then come up with an answer.

Comment: The enclosing container's layout may have default padding.